# Why default and static interface methods are not supported by Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android

Why [Default and static interface methods] of java 8 are not supported in Android Studio 3.0?

The code always got the error hint.

[image: the demo code]

The build.gradle settings :

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dreamzone.mtime"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
```

But android studio doc shows it can compatible any api level.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html
[image: android studio doc]

Comment: On that page you screenshot, did you see how to enable Java 8 support?

Comment: Thanks. It finally works after I update the Android plugin to 3.0.1.I missed that hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set Java 8 compatibility in your module's `build.gradle` file, via the `compileOptions` closure inside the `android` closure:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    // other good stuff here

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the compile options and grade sync msg error changed to `Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8. `  I found that I forgot to update Android Gradle plugin to 3.0.0 and higher, now it's ok,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// only chnage minSdkversion to more then 26

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0
  }
```